# mysql and php change single data for specific id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

This is kind of complex to me, so I hope someone can help me out.

I have a table that shows messages which are stored in a database. These messages works like a commentbox. The database that holds these messages contains the following tables:

id, name, message, urlUserOne, urlUserTwo, urlUserThree.

id is set to auto increment to create a unique number for each message.
name is used to store the name of the user who wrote the message.
message holds the message that is written.

The messages shown on the screen will be red by a fixed group of users, that's why I have the urlUserOne / urlUserTwo / etc added. They hold a text that says whether this user has red the message or not.

Beneath the message three photos are shown, one for each user. What I want is that, when an user clicks on his photo, the data that is stored in the database will change, but just for this person, so other users know that he has red the message. The text for the other users needs to stay unchanged, just the text for that user for that specific message needs to change.

How can I accomplish this? Hope someone can help!

Comment: UPDATE table SET urlUserOne = "has read" WHERE id = idOfMessage .......           is there a reason that wont work?

Comment: That will work just for urlUserOne because you specify that in the sql. But the data for SET is variable. Because if user 2 clicks his photo I need the table to update urlUserTwo, not urlUserOne.

Comment: Yes, so depending on which photo is clicked, change the SET condition....

Comment: I think you should be using a different schema if you need to have user1, user2, user3, ... as columns in one table. Maybe a many-to-many setup (table for read_by_user with user_id and message_id columns)

Comment: and make like a hundred pages to store a single line sql for each user, A.O.? Not really productive I would say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, columns in DB for each user should be boolean (TRUE for read, FALSE for unread).

Then: Add a  element to each photo, for example:

**HTML**

```
<a href="read.php?id=[MESSAGE_ID]&user=user1"><img src="pic_user1.jpg" ... /></a>
<a href="read.php?id=[MESSAGE_ID]&user=user2"><img src="pic_user2.jpg" ... /></a>
etc...
```

Then, in `read.php`

**PHP**

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_messages SET ".$_GET['user']." = true WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
execute_query($sql)
```

Let me know if it was useful.

Comment: **Please**, don't forget to validate the variables in PHP before executing the SQL Query..

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I was struggeling how to get a variable into the sql. Your example was the thing I need to work with, fixed it now! Thanks!